# dreamweaver structure xml document

Tags: xml, dreamweaver

I have an xml document where all the document content was compressed to 1 line. Is there an option in dreamweaver where I can move every tag to a new line? So it's easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands -> Apply Source Formatting  should give you a better look at your file.

Answer (score 0):

try to open the xml file in Internet Explorer. it will show the xml file in a readable manner with each tag separately.